# Finding the first string that matches a pattern in Lua (XML pattern matching)

Tags: xml, string, lua, lua-patterns

I'm currently using the following code to parse a part of an Xml file (I first read the entire file into a single string).

```
for xmlMatch in xmlString:gmatch("<MyXmlElement.*</MyXmlElement>") do
    -- Do something.
end
```

The problem I have is that the for loop is only executing once because the the gmatch function is returning only a single string, which starts at the first instance of MyXmlElement and ends at the closure of the last instance of MyXmlElement. How can I parse the string so as the the pattern is matched whenever the string `"</MyXmlElement>"` is *first* found (and not the last case only)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 3 things wrong here:

- gmatch returns the captured substrings from the string, so you need to use () around stuff you want to use in the loop
- for matching the least possible number of characters you should use `.-` as pattern to go just until the first possible `</MyXmlElement>`
- and you need variables after the for (but I guess that's just a typo)

So all together:

```
for att,cont in XmlString:gmatch'<MyXmlElement%s*(.-)>(.-)</MyXmlElement>' do
    -- something
end
```

should do the trick.

Comment: why did you use %s+ instead of %s- ?
'<MyXmlElement%s+(.-)>' will not match '<MyXmlElement>' because it expects at least 1 space after the tag name.
so it will only match MyXmlElement tags with attributes.

Comment: Good point. Only tested it with attributes. %s- is indeed better, corrected in my answer.

Comment: %s* is better in that case instead of %s-

Comment: You're right, if using -, and there are more than one space between the tag and the attributes, from the second space onwards will be captured with the attributes ... Changed in answer.